# Vim change colour for colour group in terminal

Tags: color

I'm editing Perl files in Vim in pure Linux terminal which has 16 colours.

Suppose, there is the following code:

```perl
=pod insert
 $item_ref = {
   fields
   image: Mojo::Asset::File | undef
 }
 
 Description text follows

=cut
```

Unfortunately, the text:

```perl
    fields
    image: Mojo::Asset::File | undef
```

is displayed in dark blue colour which is almost invisible upon the black background.

I found out that there are highlight groups in Vim, inserted the following function into `.vimrc`:

```
function! SynStack()
   if !exists("*synstack")
     return
   endif
   echo map(synstack(line('.'), col('.')), 'synIDattr(v:val, "name")')
endfunc
```

When I put the cursor upon the bad text, and called SynStack, I got:

```
['perlPOD', 'podVerbatimLine']
```

Then I tried to set the colour for this group in `.vimrc`:

```
hi podVerbatimLine ctermfg=white
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

How can I set the grey or white colour for this text?

After I tried: `:set termguicolors` - the colouring of text disappears.

Vim version:

```
:version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Dec 05 2023 17:58:57)
```

Comment: The highlight group reported by your function is `podVerbatim`, not `podVerbatimLine`.

Comment: Can you tell us the result of `:set termguicolors?`?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt Updated the question - the colouring disappears.

Comment: I suppose @romainl is right (he is often right ;-) ). You have to set notermguicolors (`:set notermguicolors` which is the default) since you are using a terminal that doesn't support gui colors. On our machine the text correspond to the highlighting group `podVerbatim` and not `podVerbatimLine` that is why we suggest to use that one instead (but we don't know the version of Vim you are using so we can't be sure to reproduce your problem exactly). Is the solution provided working? Which version of Vim are you using (`:version`)?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt `notermguicolors` is set by default. I added the result of `:version` into the question.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt tried to set both `hi podVerbatim ctermfg=white` and `hi podVerbatimLine ctermfg=white` in `.vimrc` - didn't work.

Comment: Does `hi Normal ctermbg=darkblue` does something?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt Added `hi Normal ctermbg=darkblue` to `.vimrc` and restarted vim. Nothing changed in that file: the normal text is not blue.

Comment: But what if you execute the command during the Vim session (I suspect your colorization to override these highlighting groups)? Can you tell us what is you colorscheme (what is the result of the `:colorscheme` Vim command)?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt `colorscheme` -> gruvbox

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt "what if you execute the command during the Vim session " - tried it. It changed the background to blue. So, seems that colorscheme somehow overrides the option we set in `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt We got the first victory: when I wrote `:hi VerbatimLine ctermfg=yellow` during the session the font colour was changed to yellow. How can I set it permanently from `.vimrc`?

Comment: I have updated the solution. `autocmd ColorScheme gruvbox highlight PreProc ctermfg=yellow`. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Always put highlight mods in a colorscheme autocmd :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `:set termguicolors?` is set I would do:

```
hi podVerbatimLine guifg=white
hi podVerbatim guifg=white
```

Otherwise I would do:

```
hi podVerbatimLine ctermfg=white
hi podVerbatim ctermfg=white
```

If the option `termguicolors` is set the gui colors are used (`guifg`, `guibg`, `guiul`).

Otherwise the cterm colors are used (`ctermfg`, `ctermbg`, `ctermul`)

In your case I suspect that `:set termguicolors?` gives `termguicolors`.

If you want to do that automatically for the `gruvbox` colorscheme you can add the following lines to your `.vimrc`

```
autocmd ColorScheme gruvbox highlight PreProc ctermfg=white
```

The gruvbox colorscheme:

- Link `podVerbatim` and `podVerbatimLine` to `PreProc`.
- Set `PreProc` to a color that you don't like

The line makes that when the colorscheme is changed to `gruvbox` the following command is executed:

```
highlight PreProc ctermfg=white
```

This will change the definition of `podVerbatim`, `podVerbatimLine` to a color that you like (`white`).

Comment: No, `termguicolors` is off by default and OP is in a 16c terminal anyway, so it is irrelevant.

Comment: There is no `podVerbatimLine`, that's OP's problem. `termguicolors` is irrelevant.

Comment: `:set termguicolors?` shows `notermguicolors`

Comment: For your terminal it is probably what it has to be. Does the second part of the solution working for you? What is the version of Vim that you are using? Do you have some special Perl plugin installed?

Comment: No, the second solution doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Can you tell us the version of Vim that you are using (you can use the Vim `:version` to find out)?

Comment: I added the line `autocmd ColorScheme gruvbox highlight PreProc ctermfg=white
` and it worked. Could you explain, what does it do? Actually `podVerbatimLine` is the correct name, so this time romainl was wrong.